# class CategoricalCrossentropy versus function categorical_crossentropy

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In Tensorflow2, I can either use the class `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy` ([defined here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy)) or the function `categorical_crossentropy` ([defined here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/categorical_crossentropy)) to compute the crossentropy loss between the labels and predictions:

For the first the code is:

```
     loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
     # ...
     @tf.function
     def train_step(samples, labels):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
          predictions = model(samples)
          loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
        #...
```

And the second is more direct:

```
   @tf.function
    def forward(features, training=False):
        predictions = model.call(...)
        loss = tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy(
                y_true=features['label'],
                y_pred=predictions)
        return loss, predictions
```

The numeric result is the same. However, I wonder whether there is an approach that is more efficient ? Or more generally, which one should be used according some particular case ?

Note that the question may be the same for any class/function [defined by the API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/losses/):

> Note that all losses are available both via a class handle and via a function handle. The class handles enable you to pass configuration arguments to the constructor (e.g. loss_fn = CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)), and they perform reduction by default when used in a standalone way (see details below).